# Django - Save model inside transaction with unsaved foreignkey

Tags: python, django

I have two Models, one of them has a ForeignKey to the other, the idea is to save them inside a transaction but it gives me an error.

These are my models:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    ...

class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    ...
```

this is my view

```
@transaction.atomic()
def save_parent(request):
    try:
        parent = Parent(name=request.POST.get('name'),other_fields).save()
        child = Child(parent=parent,other_fields).save()
        ...
    except:
        pass
```

I have looked for transaction savepoints but I dont understand them.
**My main goal is to save both or don't save anything**

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you put up the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not saving the objects correctly. Try this

```
parent = Parent(name=request.POST.get('name'),other_fields)
parent.save()
child = Child(parent=parent,other_fields)
child.save()
```

Or use the create method inside the manager.

```
parent = Parent.objects.create(name=request.POST.get('name'),other_fields)
child = Child.objects.create(parent=parent,other_fields)
```